# ¿Qué significa esto en el terminal despues de tratar de hacer el make?

Tags: c++

Saludos.

Adjunto la imagen con el issue. Si alguien me puede dar la mano lo agradezco.

Despues de darle make:

> `g++ Matrix.o Vector.o Vector3D.o matrix_main.o -o matrix_main
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:<br>
>     "UT_315::Matrix::set_cols(unsigned long)", referenced from:
>         UT_315::Vector3D::Vector3D() in Vector3D.o<br>
>     "UT_315::Matrix::set_rows(unsigned long)", referenced from:
>         UT_315::Vector3D::Vector3D() in Vector3D.o<br>
>     "UT_315::Matrix::set_value(unsigned long, unsigned long, int)", referenced from:
>         UT_315::operator>>(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, UT_315::Matrix&) in Matrix.o
>         UT_315::Vector::set_coord(int, int) in Vector.o<br>
>         UT_315::Vector::set_coord(int, int) in Vector3D.o<br>
>     "UT_315::Matrix::operator*=(int)", referenced from:<br>
>         matrix_scalar_mult() in matrix_main.o<br>
>     "UT_315::operator-(UT_315::Matrix const&, UT_315::Matrix const&)", referenced from:<br>
>         matrix_substraction() in matrix_main.o<br>
>     "UT_315::operator*(UT_315::Matrix const&, UT_315::Matrix const&)", referenced from:<br>
>         matrix_multiplication() in matrix_main.o<br>
>     "UT_315::operator+(UT_315::Matrix const&, UT_315::Matrix const&)", referenced from:<br>
>         matrix_addition() in matrix_main.o<br>
>     "UT_315::Matrix::get_cols() const", referenced from:<br>
>         UT_315::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, UT_315::Matrix const&) in Matrix.o<br>
>         UT_315::Matrix::operator+=(UT_315::Matrix const&) in Matrix.o<br>
>         UT_315::Matrix::operator-=(UT_315::Matrix const&) in Matrix.o<br>
>     "UT_315::Matrix::get_rows() const", referenced from:<br>
>         UT_315::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, UT_315::Matrix const&) in Matrix.o<br>
>         UT_315::Matrix::operator+=(UT_315::Matrix const&) in Matrix.o<br>
>         UT_315::Matrix::operator-=(UT_315::Matrix const&) in Matrix.o<br>
>         UT_315::Vector::get_dimensions() const in Vector.o<br>
>         UT_315::Vector::length() const in Vector.o<br>
>     "UT_315::Matrix::get_value(unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:<br>
>         UT_315::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, UT_315::Matrix const&) in Matrix.o<br>
>         UT_315::Matrix::operator+=(UT_315::Matrix const&) in Matrix.o<br>
>         UT_315::Matrix::operator-=(UT_315::Matrix const&) in Matrix.o<br>
>         UT_315::Vector::get_coord(int) const in Vector.o<br>
>         UT_315::Vector::get_coord(int) const in Vector3D.o<br>
>     "UT_315::Matrix::transpose() const", referenced from:<br>
>         matrix_transpose() in matrix_main.o<br>
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64<br>
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)<br>
>   make: *** [matrix_main] Error 1`

Comment: No se ve nada. Y si pudieras copiarlo y ponerlo como texto, *mas mejor* ;-)

Comment: ya puse el contenido

Answer (score 1):

Los mensajes no dejan lugar a dudas: el enlazador **no encuentra** el cuerpo de algunas funciones; las primeras que aparecen son

1. `UT_315::Matrix::set_cols(unsigned long);`
2. `UT_315::Matrix::set_rows(unsigned long);`
3. `UT_315::Matrix::set_value(unsigned long, unsigned long, int);`
4. ...

Es decir, has declarado una clase `UT_315::Matrix` en la que declaras esas funciones, pero, por alguna razón, el enlazador no encuentra dichas funciones; puede ser porque, efectivamente, **no estén** en el código, o porque tangas algún conflicto con los `namespace`; tal vez las has declarado en uno, y las has implementado en otro. O tal vez los nombres de los archivos no coincidan, esos nombres con la inicial en mayúscula para los archivos objeto ...

Para concretar la respuesta, deberías mostrar algo de los archivos que te producen el error (posiblemente matrix.hpp y matrix.cpp), así como la parte del `Makefile` en la que se indican las órdenes para generarlos.